# Canvas image quality issue

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to simulate the `background-size: cover` property in canvas. I got it working, but the quality is bad.

**Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kwd5L/4/)**. You can compare the two images(zoom out so you can see both image next to each other):

My code looks like:

```
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetY) {
    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        newW = iw * r,
        newH = ih * r,
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    if (newW < w) ar = w / newW;
    if (newH < h) ar = h / newH;
    newW *= ar;
    newH *= ar;

    cw = iw / (newW / w);
    ch = ih / (newH / h);

    cy = -parseInt(offsetY) * ih / newH;

    ctx.patternQuality = 'best';
    ctx.antialias = 'default';
    ctx.filter = 'default';

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, cy, cw, ch, x, y, w, h);
```

I've tried adding

```
ctx.patternQuality = 'best';
ctx.antialias = 'default';
ctx.filter = 'default';
```

in order to improve quality, but I'm still no getting enough good quality. Is it possible to  use the original quality image in canvas.

Also `parseInt(x)` and `parseInt(x) + 0.5` to the cordinates, didn't fixed the problem.

**This question is tagged with `nodejs` because I'm using this code in nodejs with the node-canvas module.*

Comment: Some good info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946608/canvas-drawimage-quality

Comment: Tried with both parseInt and parseInt + 0.5, still not getting nice quality: http://jsfiddle.net/Kwd5L/5/

Comment: I suspect that there are some rounding inaccuracies in your math which cause the blur.

Comment: Canvas typically uses bi-linear interpolation when resizing images while image elements typically use bicubic which produce better results. Try to add a sharpener convolution to the result to sharpen it up (see f.ex. this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235791/1693593). Ps. code from SO must be attributed..

Answer (score 2):

Try setting imageSmoothingEnabled property to false on the context:

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

By default canvas using bilinear filter when scaling. It is blurry. You may need nearest-neighbor filtering, which is a mere pixel repetition.